# Pass variable to class implemented in a script loaded with Roslyn

Tags: c#, scripting, roslyn

I'm trying to implement a script evaluator to evaluate some classes that my users will implement that will have a fixed entry point accepting a variable that will be given from the main application.

To do this I've declared a namespace that contains the type of the object that will be passed to the entry point. This is the whole code that declares the custom type and executes the scripts:

```
namespace MyNamespace
{
    public class Vertex
    {
        public float X { get; } = 0.0f;
        public float Y { get; } = 0.0f;
        public float Z { get; } = 0.0f;

        public Vertex(float x, float y, float z)
        {
            X = x;
            Y = y;
            Z = z;
        }

        public override string ToString()
        {
            return string.Format("[{0}, {1}, {2}]", X, Y, Z);
        }
    }
}

public class Globals
{
    public Vertex testVertex = new Vertex(0, 0, 0);
    public int testValue = 100;
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        try
        {
            ScriptOptions options = ScriptOptions.Default;

            // Add assemblies
            options = options.AddReferences(
                typeof(System.Object).GetTypeInfo().Assembly,
                typeof(System.Linq.Enumerable).GetTypeInfo().Assembly,
                typeof(MyNamespace.Vertex).GetTypeInfo().Assembly
            );

            // Add usings
            options = options.AddImports("System");
            options = options.AddImports("System.Linq");
            options = options.AddImports("System.Collections.Generic");
            options = options.AddImports("MyNamespace");

            var script = <added below>;

            Globals globals = new Globals();

            ScriptState<object> scriptState = CSharpScript.RunAsync(script, options: options, globals: globals).Result;
            scriptState = scriptState.ContinueWithAsync(@"Figure fig = new Figure();").Result;
            scriptState = scriptState.ContinueWithAsync(@"fig.Draw(testVertex);").Result;
        }
        catch (CompilationErrorException e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(string.Join(Environment.NewLine, e.Diagnostics));
        }
    }
}
```

And this is an example of a script that I'm trying to load:

```
public class Figure
{
    public void Draw(Vertex v)
    {
        System.Console.WriteLine(v.ToString());
    }

    public void Draw(int i)
    {
        System.Console.WriteLine(i);
    }
}
```

Now, the problem is that when I call the method `Draw` of the class `Figure` inside the script, it throws me an exception saying

```
error CS1503: Argument 1: cannot convert from 'MyNamespace.Vertex [~/Projects/ScriptTest/ScriptTest/bin/Debug/netcoreapp1.0/ScriptTest.dll]' to 'MyNamespace.Vertex [ScriptTest, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null]'
```

When I do

```
scriptState = scriptState.ContinueWithAsync(@"fig.Draw(testValue);").Result; // Using testValue instead of testVertex
```

everything works fine.

It think the problem is that the script is referring to a different namespace than `MyNamespace` but I don't know how to solve this.

Comment: wondering if you ever got anywhere with this? I have the exact same issue. My class is available to use and instantiate new objects inside the script methods but I can't use it to pass an object of that type as a parameter via globals.